# How to delete 1000 records based upon created date ascending using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, sql-server-2014

I have a requirement to delete last 1000 records from a table based upon created date and then insert new 1000 records from a different table.

What would be the best possible way to do it?

```
public void mymethod()
{
     // TestBasketRequests (delete thousands records from here)
     // Call Delete();
}

public void Delete(IList<TestBasketRequest> TestBasketRequests)
{
    using (var dbContext = new myContext())
    {
        dbContext.Entry(TestBasketRequests).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you've luxury of using third party library, I would recommend to use [EntityFramework.Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus) as it provides batch delete method in asynchronous mode.

Comment: Do you want to add data to the second table with same table schema?

Answer (score 2):

The

```
RemoveRange()
```

method is used to delete multiple items from the database. And in the method you have to use to get the last 1000 items using

```
TakeLast()
```

will only return last items based on the order they were added to the database.

Inside your mymethod() u have to write something like this

```
var lastN = MyDbContext.MyDbSet
                   .OrderByDescending(g => g.CreateDate)
                   .Take(1000);

MyDbContext.MyDbSet.RemoveRange(lastN);
```

I didnt test this code.you can make changes as per your requirements.